# Probability as a function of time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, soft-question

I was really wondering when I have to select any one out of the n options available - the probability of selecting A (let's say) is 1/n.

But then I'm confused. When I (or anyone/anything else) bring my hand close to B (let's say) won't the probability of selecting B increase? And since any information can't be transferred more than the speed of light*, obviously all this (my hand's movements) at not happening at infinite speed, instantly.

Now, if I plot a graph of probability vs time: it will vary from person to person (considering humans experimenting). What exacting is causing this and how is it related to 1/n?

$^*$Is this a flaw in our probability theory?

Thanks to anyone trying to shed light on this. :)

Comment: If I understand right, you doubt that a selection out of $n$ objects produces probability $\frac{1}{n}$ for each object to be chosen. That might be true. But probability theory can handle different probabilities as well. So, I do not understand the point. Of course, it can be difficult or impossible to find out the actual probabilities.

Comment: Many exercises assume (mostly unmentioned), that the probabilities are actually equal. This is not necessarily true if you let choose a number from $1$ to $100$, for example. But complicated probabilities can only be calculated if some simpler probabilities are either assumed or known.

Comment: @Peter Do you mean to say that for the probability to be equal to 1/n we have assumed that the process takes place instantly?

Comment: What do instantly hapenning processes have to do with equal probabilities? I still do not understand. Flipping a coin is a process taking time. Do you doubt that "heads" and "tails" have equal probability because of this fact ?

Comment: There is no implicit assumption about how long the process takes, because this doesn't even make sense to talk about. When we do problems in probability, we reduce a situation to a mathematical abstraction; there is no implicit concept of time in such an abstraction. In a certain problem, we might *assume* that each item has probability $\frac{1}{n}$ of being picked. If we find that this does not reflect the reality of what we are trying to analyze, we can adjust our assumptions.

Comment: I think this scenario can be modelled pretty much the way you imagine it by having a different filtration for each observer and look at the expectation of the outcome conditioned on each filtration. That is the point of a filtration in the first place: conditional probabilities of certain events depends on what information you have, and this information might be different for different observers.

Comment: @slug OK, this could be the intention of the OP.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of "reality", not mathematics. If you have $n$ different, indistinguishable objects and you pick one **at random**, than the probabilty for every object to be picked is $p=\frac{1}{n}$. However, you're problem arises, when you assigning the picking process to a person. A person might not pick fully at random.

An observation from a magicians point of view: whenever I ask someone to pick a card (meaning to pick a card at random) and I spread the deck, most of the times people go for a card in the center of the deck. It might have something to do with them thinking, that I might know the top card or the bottom card, but I definitely cannot know a card from the center. If you analyse this process mathematically, there should be chance of $\frac{1}{52}$ for any card to be picked but (without having any hard data) I'd guess that it is more like $\frac{1}{100}$ for each of the top five/bottom five cards.